# How to save the collect-view tool node info in a .pcap file

Tags: cooja

i need help in Cooja simulation i want to save the collect view tool node info in a pcap file any one can help, i want to generate a large amount of data for scientific research, the node info have the AVG which i want to remove

Comment: Show us some of your code or effort that you put into your work

Comment: Simas Joneliunas  i am working in rpl framework from github and i want to generate dataset for research so i need to save the node info from collect-view tool in a .pcap file